# C++ 11/14 Unique Pointer not so unique?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr

I have just stabled upon a situation were a unique_pointer reference was passed as function argument. So I took a look at it and found out that the code was actually comping and running.

Why is that possible?
How is a pointer unique when you can have reference of that pointer?

Here my example:

```
class Foo{
    public:
    int bar{23};
};

void Bar(std::unique_ptr<Foo>& a_foo){
    a_foo->bar = 42;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    auto foo{ std::make_unique<Foo>() };
    Bar(foo);
    std::cout << foo->bar << std::endl; //outputs 42

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Unique" refers to "unique ownership".

Comment: Do. you know the get method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is a pointer unique when you can have reference of that pointer?

You can have as many references to that pointer as you like, but there is still indeed only one of them.

Remove the `&` so that you attempt to copy the `unique_ptr`, and your program won't build. You're not allowed to clone/copy the pointer so that there is more than one pointing to the same thing. That's what the "unique" means.

Answer (score 3):

A reference doesn't create a new instance of the pointer. Just because you can refer to the pointer doesn't mean it's not unique. I can refer to you by name, that doesn't mean I've cloned you every time I use your name :) A reference in C++ is - in this respect - like a person's name.

Comment: A nice analogy!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my what I wanted to answer and maybe didn't phrase correctly is: that isn't the idea of behind a unique pointer to be unique? if you can reference it everywhere else whats the point of it, you can still change it, why not use a shared?

Comment: @C.Michael When you use a reference, it's up to you to ensure that the reference doesn't become a dangling reference. In other words, the compiler can't prevent you from designing your software incorrectly. If you need a shared pointer, use it not because you expect the compiler to force you to, but because it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Kuba Ober.  Kuba Ober.  Kuba Ober.  Now, you are outnumbered.